# What is the difference between the function in an object and the get function in an object?

Tags: javascript, function, getter

// My code for example an object with getter

```
let person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  language : "en",
  **get lang()** {
    return this.language;
  }
};

console.log(person.lang) // returns "en"

// versus 

let person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  language : "en",
  **lang() {**
    return this.language;
  }
};

console.log(person.lang()); //returns "en"
```

So the only difference with the getter method that I don't have to put parenthesis after the function name while calling it, is that it only?

Comment: Yes that's basically it. When there's a getter function, an expression that looks like a simple property reference is really a function call to the getter function.

Comment: @Pointy it is a surprise for me. Thought there was something more behind the getters, what about setters, is it the same case about the setters?

Comment: Yes, `x.property = y;` is treated as a function call to the setter, with `y` as the single parameter.

Comment: @Pointy thank you very much. I am a newbie here, can you tell me if I have to delete the post or finish (if yes, how?) it, if someone (in this case you) answered to my question?

Comment: Don't worry about it; it may get closed eventually as being a non-problem but you are not obligated to take any action.